# Background gradient working but not displaying image

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am having issues getting this to work, for context I am making a simple stat tracking website and `.body-bg-image` is for my home page.

I want a gradient for my background, not a solid color, so I tried to do that as you can see below. It does show the gradient but does not show the image anymore.

```
.body-bg-image {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to top,
        rgba(196, 145, 2, 1) 0%,
        rgba(149, 48, 54, 1) 87%
    )
    fixed,
    /* this image doesn't show, 
    it works if I have the background as a color but not as a gradient */
    url("./assets/apexrevanant.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```

It used to work when it was like this, just a solid primary color and the image:

```
.body-bg-image {
    background: var(--primary-color) url("./assets/apexrevanant.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, no problem there. Maybe you should describe your problem a bit more and show us some code

Comment: Yea sorry about that added some context and fixed the code, I don't know how to use stackoverflow that well.

Comment: No prob, but you see, better description and some code and you have a good answer quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `background` shorthand, **order matters.**

Linear gradient adds an overlay to the image if the image is declared after the gradient. As you have solid colors, it won't be visible.

If you set the colors to a lower opacity you should be able to see it:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(196, 145, 2, 0.5) 0%, rgba(149, 48, 54, 0.5) 87%) fixed, url('https://mobiledevmemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/173572251_Chocolate-chip-cookie.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

---

If you want the image *in front* of the gradient **reverse the order they are declared in**:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://mobiledevmemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/173572251_Chocolate-chip-cookie.jpg') top center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top, rgba(196, 145, 2, 0.5) 0%, rgba(149, 48, 54, 0.5) 87%) fixed;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```